# Changing position of an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, positioning

I'm building a Wordpress theme and I have a problem with footer position. Index page is fine, I defined in style.css margin-top of "footer", witch holds bckimage to 900px and margin-top of "foot_sadrzaj" to 918px, because "foot_sadrzaj" holds text and images. Here's link: http://casabianca.ba/test/

Well, if I go to page, content of the page is in  or, when displaying posts, in . I wrote some JS code to change position of a footer and foot_sadrzaj depending on position and height of sadrzaj or sadrzaj_single, elements containing content, but it doesn't work (like here: http://casabianca.ba/test/novosti/).... Can you help me figure out why?

Here,s the code:

```
var div = getElementById('sadrzaj');
var div2 = getElementById('sadrzaj_single');


if (div) {
    var z = div.style.offsetTop+div.style.offsetHeight;
    getElementById('footer').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + z.toString() + "px");
    getElementById('foot_sadrzaj').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + (z+18).toString() + "px");
}
else if (div2) {
    var z = div2.style.offsetTop+div2.style.offsetHeight;
    getElementById('footer').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + z.toString() + "px");
    getElementById('foot_sadrzaj').setAttribute(
            "style", "marginTop:" + (z+18).toString() + "px");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If possible, You may try jQuery.

jQuery has got a lot of positioning options including CSS styling.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Just suggesting jQuery is not very useful

Comment: Don't know JQuery and don't have time right now for it... I'm pushed with deadline, otherwise I would try to rewrite all from the scratch... Thnx anyway..